# why isn't there a Math.floor(float)?

Tags: java

Why is there only Math.floor(double)?

I have a float and I want to round it "down".
do I have to cast it to double?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It will be converted automatically (see this on [widening primitive conversions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html#25214)).  If you want the result as a `float`, however, you will need to explicitly cast the return value.

Comment: Thanks. so basically - getting the integer value of a float with this function will cast my float to double and return me a double that I should cast to an int . this sounds slow.

Comment: @user: Converting from a `float` to a `double` should take almost zero time.  And you have no alternative but to convert the result!

Comment: If you're using floor(float) just to get the int value... just cast straight to int.

Comment: @Gordon Unless it's negative, since e.g. `Math.floor(-1.5) != (int)-1.5`

Answer (score 9):

Yes, but when speed is critical support for single precision floats should be provided. There should be a single precision analogous for java.lang.Math

Answer (score 3):

No, a `float` primitive will automatically be cast to a `double` without the loss of any precision.

Comment: there is a loss: the following is true: (double).9f != .9d
Ideally there should be Math api for floats

Answer (score 3):

A double is big enough to exactly represent every single possible float and more. You are not going to lose any precision, the cast happens automatically.

Answer (score 2):

`float` and `double`, both are floating point data types with double having larger range. You should be able to use your float variable with Math.Floor(double) without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the float without doing a cast as a float has less precision than a double.